# I'm trying to make a filter table using the code attached, is it alright?

Tags: angular

[the code is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSane.jpg)
I have attached the code in the photograph attached in this message because the code is long.

Please check for me, I am trying to make a filter table using that code.

Answer (score 0):

First, please not attach images, just copy the **important parts of code** in the question, selected and use Ctrl+K to formatted (It's really hard read a question based in images)

Second, use a simple function with two arguments,e.g.

```
(click)="filterYear(0,20)"
(click)="filterYear(21,30)"
...
```

Idem with gender

```
(click)="filterGender('male')"
(click)="filterGender('female')"
(click)="filterGender(null)"
```

You need store in three variables the gender and the min and max years

I imagine you has two variables "data" and "dataFiltered". So your function filter should be like

```
filterYear(min:number,max:number)
{
    this.min=min;
    this.max=max;
    this.filter(); //call to the function filter
}
filtergender(gender:any)
{
    this.gender=gender
    this.filter();
}

filter()
{
  this.dataFiltered=this.data.filter(x=>x.year>=min && x.prop<=year && 
        (!this.gender || x.gender==this.gender)

}
```

See that the last condition is true if this.gender has no value or gender is equal to this.gender

NOTE: I don't know about your data, so I imagine that you has an array of object with "year and "gender" properties